# Typo3 scheduler class not found

Tags: php, typo3, php-5.3

I am trying to get a scheduler class running on typo3.

ext_autoload.php:

```
$extensionPath = t3lib_extMgm::extPath('mh_compass');
$loaderClass = array(
    'tx_monitorcompassdailyreset_sched' => $extensionPath.'scheduler/class.tx_monitorcompassdailyreset_sched.php',
);
return $loaderClass;
```

ext_localconf.php:

```
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['scheduler']['tasks']['tx_monitorcompassdailyreset_sched'] = array(
      'extension'        => $_EXTKEY,
      'title'            => 'Compass Monitor Daily Reset Scheduler',
      'description'      => 'Reset daily Monitor Jobs',
  );
```

class.tx_monitorcompassdailyreset_sched.php:

```
class tx_monitorcompassdailyreset_sched extends tx_scheduler_Task {

    public function execute() {
        error_log( "Start Compass Monitor Daily Reset Scheduled Job" );
        //do some stuff
        error_log( "Finished Compass Monitor Scheduled Job" );
    }
}
```

When I try to add the task in the scheduler in the backend, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'tx_monitorcompassdailyreset_sched' not found in /var/www/typo3_src-4.5.22/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php on line 5375
```

This doesn't make sense as a) I have used debug on that function and it loads all the other classes, and b) I cannot see a discrepancy in my class naming.

The version of php is 5.3.10 (there was a bug like this with 5.3.2, but it disappeared)

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Class names are cached. It might be easier if you would follow the naming conventions.

Comment: Yes the cache was cleared. I'm quite new to typo3 and working on something another developer started so I didn't realize the naming convention (which is?) was not being followed.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using?
Can you provide a .t3x-file of this extension? Then i could have a look at it.

Comment: Not possible I am afraid. It's spec work for a client who I doubt would let me. However, what I posted above is actually exactly the patch to the extension that adds the new scheduler task (except the "//do some stuff" bit, which only updates some values in a db). The rest of the extension has no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class naming is obviously wrong. Your extension key is "mh_compass", so your class name needs to start with "tx_mhcompass_". The beginning of the class name always contains "tx_" followed up with the extension key without underscores.

Try renaming your class to "tx_mhcompass_Task_Reset" for example.